# If statement iterating throughout column of VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro to iterate through a column and change a value in a separate column if a parameter is met in a specific cell from the first column. Here is what I have:

```
If Range(AB) <> 0 Then
    AD = "Basketball"
Else
    AD = "Football"
End If
```

How do I set the range for my cells to be generic while iterating through the entire column?

Comment: Take a look at `For` Loop which should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this can be done with formulas too and there is no need for VBA. In most cases formulas are faster than using VBA, because VBA does not support multi threading.

#### Formula

Therfore just add this formula in column AD:

```
=If(AB:AB<>0, "Basketball", "Football")
```

#### VBA

The general structure would be using a `For` loop:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'reference your sheet

Dim LastRow As Long  'find last used row in column A. Adjust column to your needs
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim iRow As Long
For iRow = 1 To LastRow  'loop from first to last row and do the following in each row
    If ws.Cells(iRow, "AB").Value <> 0 Then
        ws.Cells(iRow, "AD").Value = "Basketball"
    Else
        ws.Cells(iRow, "AD").Value = "Football"
    End If
Next iRow
```